# Node.Js stuck mid-way through installation with Chocolatey. After a bit failures noted

Tags: node.js, chocolatey

I recently reset my pc while doing my usual cleanups, and I was re-installing node.js, for an application that uses it. However, unlike the first time, when I opt to install it with  Chocolatey, it gets stuck on installing python then when I tried to copy it everything finished up but I got failures with

Chocolatey upgraded 16/19 packages. 3 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures

- visualstudio2019buildtools (exited 404) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019buildtools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
  See log for details.
- python311 (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python311\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
  See log for details.
- visualstudio2019-workload-vctools (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.

I'm not tech literate...idk what to do...Any help would be welcome.

Didn't try anything since well...i'm not sure what's going on here.